# Свои(либо правленые) функции в плагинах и composer update

Tags: php, composer

Вот я поставил на CakePHP плагин CakeDC/Users. Поправил некоторые функции, дописал свои, в частности редактирование профиля, потом сделал composer update (не подумав) и всё слетело, файлы обновились и все мои труды ушли в трубу. Возможно ли безболезненно используя пространство имён плагина писать свои функции чтоб потом спокойно обновляться, и как это сделать? Или же копировать, а потом после каждого обновления копипастить? Не хочется лепить костылей. Я уверен что есть оптимальный вариант, только где его найти... Аксакалы композера отзовитесь пожалуйста.Вариант убрать ^ в composer.json не рассматриваю :)

Answer (score 1):

Самый оптимальный, на мой взгляд, вариант — это использовать наследование.
Не изменяйте код в vendor.

1. Определите в вашем проекте пространство имен для загруженного
   плагина
2. Создавайте там классы-наследники от классов плагина, что
   лежат в папке vendor, которые собираетесь изменить/модифицировать
3. Работайте с ними